# How to extract and reuse common part for this yaml fragment?

Tags: yaml, circleci

In a circleci config.yml file I have a number of jobs  defined similarly this way:

```
defaults: &defaults
  working_directory: ~/repo/appengine
  docker:
    - image: circleci/python

version: 2
jobs:
  deploy_uat:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/repo
      - checkout
      - run: *setup_secret
      - run: *enable_npm
      - run: *appengine_dep
      - run: *webview_dep
      - run: *apps_dep
      - run:
          name: Setup key file
          command: |
            mkdir ~/gcloud_keys
            echo ${GCLOUD_UAT_ENV_KEY} | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ${HOME}/gcloud_keys/uat-env.json
      - run: deployt.sh uat
  deploy_dev:
    # ... Skipped for brevity
  deploy_staging:
    # ...
```

I would like to further simplify the yaml code to something like this

```
defaults: &defaults
  working_directory: ~/repo/appengine
  docker:
    - image: circleci/python

# Common steps
deploy_steps: &deploy_steps
  steps:
    - attach_workspace:
        at: ~/repo
    - checkout
    - run: *setup_secret
    - run: *enable_npm
    - run: *appengine_dep
    - run: *webview_dep
    - run: *apps_dep

version: 2
jobs:
  deploy_uat:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      *deploy_steps
      - run:
          name: Setup key file
          command: |
            mkdir ~/gcloud_keys
            echo ${GCLOUD_UAT_ENV_KEY} | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ${HOME}/gcloud_keys/uat-env.json
      - run: deployt.sh uat

  deploy_dev:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      *deploy_steps
      - run:
          name: Setup key file
          command: |
            mkdir ~/gcloud_keys
            echo ${GCLOUD_DEV_ENV_KEY} | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ${HOME}/gcloud_keys/dev-env.json
      - run: deployt.sh dev

  deploy_staging:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      *deploy_steps
      - run:
          name: Setup key file
          command: |
            mkdir ~/gcloud_keys
            echo ${GCLOUD_STAGING_ENV_KEY} | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ${HOME}/gcloud_keys/staging-env.json
      - run: deployt.sh staging
```

However if I do it this way, I got **did not find expected key** error at the line `*deploy_steps`

If I change it to

```
  deploy_uat:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      <<: *deploy_steps
      # ...
```

I got the same error

What is the right way to write simpler yaml config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the value of `steps` is expected to be an array. In the first case, there is an alias which points to a mapping (containing a `steps` key), followed by two sequence items. This is not a valid YAML structure and won't even get past the parser.

In the second case, you are using the (deprecated) [merge key](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html). That is only defined for mappings, there is no equivalent for sequences.

What you want to do is to merge two sequences inside YAML. There is no way to do that as YAML is not a programming language and does not support transformations on input data (apart from the merge key, which current YAML devs agree was a bad idea from the start).

Since YAML does not allow you to do what you want, you can turn to templating languages like Jinja, which is what Ansible and SaltStack do to enable doing such things in their YAML configs. Since CircleCI does not support it, you'd need to write yourself a script to transform your input YAML into the version CircleCI understands. It's up to you whether this is a feasible solution to your problem.